# Error while trying to convert to Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-library

I am trying to convert an Angular 8 app to Angular 9. While running ngcc I see that i get:

> getInternalNameOfClass() called on a non-ES5 class: expected
>   AwesomeComponent to have an inner class declaration

AwesomeComponent is a component from our shared library.

Is there a fix for this error?

Comment: need attach some code to question to triage it

Answer (score 1):

Try changing  `compilerOptions` of your `tsconfig.json` from `es5` to `es2015`

Answer (score 0):

I make extensive use of shared components in my project.  Perhaps one difference is that I import modules and not components directly.

If you want to take a look at my setup running on Angular9, here's my GitHub repo:
https://github.com/ikemtz/AngularMonoRepo/blob/master/src/libs/imng-auth0-oidc/src/lib/auth0-oidc.module.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer, are your shared libraries compiled using Angular 9 as well? I am not importing individual components as well. Angular is using ngcc to go through each component in the shared library modules and throwing this error.

Comment: Yes, everything is on Angular 9 and these libraries are shared on npm.  Do you have a repo that you can share?  Or repro steps?

Comment: Oh okay. My shared libraries are still in Angular 8 so when I was consuming them in the app, the ng compatibility compiler was kicking in and trying to convert them. The error I got was when it was trying to do that. Because of IP, I would not be able to post the project on an open platform I am afraid.